# What is T_reboot in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-pro

In my Startup tab in Task Manager, I see an app called T_reboot. It says Enabled and the startup impact isn't measured. The other apps I have are:

```
Intel(R) Graphics Command Center Startup Task (Enabled, Not measured)

LinkedIn (Disabled, None)

Phone Link (Disabled, None)

Realtek HD Audio Universal Service (Enabled, Medium)

Steam (Disabled, None)

Update (this is Discord) (Disabled, None)

Windows Security notification icon (Enabled, Low)
```

I'm using Windows 10 Pro, 4GB of RAM

Comment: Use a tool like AutoRuns to identify the process and edit your question with enough information to answer your question

Comment: I think this is something you installed. I do not have this here on 2 different machines I am looking at. Nothing in Bing AI either.

Comment: Right click it and then select either "search online" or ""browse" or even "properties" and then tell us what you see.

Comment: @Ramhound Can't find it in AutoRuns.

Comment: @Mokubai Can't select Open file location or Properties, when I select "Search online" it just searches "t_reboot.exe T_reboot" in Bing.

Comment: It is likely a virus.  Do an offline scan with Windows Defender.

Comment: @John Doing a virus scan right now, path is "C:\TEST_TOOL\Misc\t_reboot.exe". Can't navigate to the folder in CMD or Explorer. Not on my other laptop.

Comment: @BL1Z33 - You can’t find AutoRuns if you search for it on Google? What other files are in Test_Tool? I have serious doubts it’s a virus

Comment: @Ramhound I downloaded AutoRuns but can't find T_reboot in it. Also can't navigate to the folder.

Comment: @BL1Z33 - Care to explain in greater detail?

Comment: Have you visited https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197450 ?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No I haven't. Haven't done any of these things on the site before either.

Comment: @John Done the virus scan (a bit over 1.5m files) and nothing got flagged.